# Render content elements from records field in a fluid template?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-9.x, fluid-styled-content

I have a custom content element that uses the records field. How can I put the records in this field into my fluid template?

I have tried doing this:

```
ext_example < lib.contentElement
ext_example {
    templateName = MyTemplate
    dataProcessing {
        10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\SplitProcessor
        10 {
          fieldName = records
          delimiter = ,
        }
    }
}
```

But it gives an array like this: `'tt_content_26,tt_content_30'`
How do I remove the prefix `tt_content_` so I have a uid array that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Per default, the records field allows only "tt_content" records. So, you have a list of UIDs of tt_content records in this field, but you're using these **UID**s in the **pid**InList.

Comment: If there's a type prefix in front of the UIDs, the records field is configured to allow different types of records. In this case, using the value of the records field in a query is difficult - because you do not know if there are only UIDs of the expected type.

If you are **really** sure about the value, you might use stdWrap function (e.g replacement)

Comment: So if records gives me `tt_content_1,tt_content_2,tt_content_3` how do I use replacement with SplitProcessor to get just the numbers?

Comment: By using the SplitProcessor, you cannot modify/manipulate your input value. It splits simply the value of the given fieldName. Using the DatabaseQueryProcessor was a better solution.
`uidInList {
  field = records
  stdWrap.replacement {
    10 {
      search = tt_content_
      replace =
    }
  }
}`